# Can we use IE Dev tool to identify what is causing scroll bar to jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a component that contains a textbox, & this textbox grows (height increases) as you enter text. Within this control user can add multiple such textbox dynamically. Now lets say user enters 5000 chars in first textbox and add another one (just below it) and add 6000 chars. after doing this when user clicks somewhere outside or on first textbox, page scrollbar automatically adjust themselves and moves up and down. How can I identify in dev toolbar what is causing this issue.

I am trying to add a sample but I am unable to do so. I will continue to work on it. Meanwhile, is it possible to identify using dev toolbar, what is causing scrollbar to go up and down ?

Comment: It is really going to be impossible for us to help debug it or give advice since we are in the dark. What scroll is moved? The textarea? The page?

Comment: I suggest using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in a page, in the editor toolbar) to create your sample.

Comment: @epascarello: page's scrollbar moves. I am trying to create fiddle and will share it as soon as its ready. Currently i just want to know what is causing this behavior

Comment: We can provide a solid suggestion once you post a sample code. Without that, it is hard to make any comment about the cause of the issue. Does this issue only occur in an IE 11 browser? What result do you get in the other browsers? Also, let us know what is the expected output?